# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/publicsuffixes.gz'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After adding:

```
implementation (group: 'ir.databeen.sdk', name: 'databeenlib', version: '1.0.2', ext: 'aar')
```

I have this error when I want to generate my app:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path
>   'okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/publicsuffixes.gz'

Here are my Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.cedarmaps:CedarMapsSDK:3.1.2'
implementation 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.4.1'
implementation 'ir.tapsell.sdk:tapsell-sdk-android:4.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation (group: 'ir.databeen.sdk', name: 'databeenlib', version: '1.0.2', ext: 'aar')
implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

I tried to use:

```
implementation (group: 'ir.databeen.sdk', name: 'databeenlib', version: '1.0.2', ext: 'aar'){
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp'
}
```

but the error still persists.

Comment: did you solve ?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Having the same issue when trying to import retrofit locally as modules..